# How to set height of cell editor based on content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ag-grid

I have this ag-grid table with the **cellEditor** `agRichSelectCellEditor` and I want the height to be set to the same size as content by default. In the picture attached I have space in the bottom of my `agRichSelectCellEditor` and I want the size of the editor to be the same size as content and remove the space in the bottom. **with more than 4 options it works fine** and there is no space in the bottom.

```
 cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor"
```

[image: Example image]

This seems to be the standard in **ag-grid cell editors**, if you click on male in the **cellEditor** example in the **official doc** it seems to have empty space here too (See image below). Here is a link to ag-grid cell editor doc which includes an example of the table which has the same "issue":  [Cell editing Ag-grid-angular documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/cell-editing/#example-dynamic-parameters)

Plunker example of the case: [Ag-grid agRichSelectCellEditor example](https://plnkr.co/edit/eNUwAP827CI9e6HG)

[image]

Is it possible to modify the default minimum height to depend on content size in ag-grid?

Comment: could you create a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)?

Comment: Added link to the official doc of ag-grid where there is an example of the same case and also the source code,

Comment: It would  be very nice if your provide [a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular) as there is no TypeScript examples in link you provided

Comment: Updated question with an example in plunker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following style should make `height` of list to fit to size of its content:

```
div.ag-rich-select .ag-rich-select-list {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 100% !important;    
}
```

However, styles are not overriden. It looks like that styles should be overriden through some code like [it is described in the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/cell-styles/) or [by adding the above class](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/getting-started/) to `style.scss` file.